# CSS Responsive Images - Don't Load / Remove large size images in mobile

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on Responsive site which has many large images...

I am aware of how to resize/hide the images for mobile devices. In this case, images are loading and hiding which is causing more internet data from the user's device.

Instead, I dont want to load the large images if somebody is viewing on the mobile

Any Help Please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import you're image in css like that :

```
@media screen and (min-width:800px){
    .class{
    background-image:url('large.png');
    }
}
```

and redefine you're class for mobile

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
   .class{
      background-image:none;
   }
}
```

Comment: **@Alexis**, This seems to be good solutions... Thanks for the **TIP** :)